# Entity framework LINQ query 2 tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am unable to use the `Include("CITies")` extension method on the `db.Restaurants` object.

When I use the include I get the following error:
 `DL.RESTAURANT does nto contain a definition for include or an extension method of include`

```
namespace DL
{
    public class DLgetRestaurants
    {
        DL.FVRGDataContext db = new FVRGDataContext();

        public IEnumerable <RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
        {
           var restaurantList = 
               from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITies")
               where RESTAURANT.CITies.Any(t => t.CITY_ID == 2)
               orderby RESTAURANT.REST_NAME ascending
               select RESTAURANT;

            return restaurantList;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: @Aducci that was my bad accidentally edited it out. It's back

Comment: What's the datatype of `db.RESTAURANTS`?

Comment: did u add the namespace `System.Data.Entity` to your file?

Comment: no I didn't .... Intellisense can't seem to find 'Entity'

Comment: db is my DataContext file and RETAURANT is a table in my entity framewaor,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the Include on Entities that have a relation with another table. Other than that you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: The RESTAURANT table has a foreign key relationship to the CITY table.  I have set up the datacontect file with those tables (and others).  Is that not sufficient?